# A JCL or a SORTCARD that can split the input file into multiple output files based on size of the input file

Tags: syncsort

I have a large input file that i would want to split it into more than output file if the size input file is greater than 10 MB and i want the header record from the input to be copied to all the output files that are catalogued

Example :
a) If i receive a file of 42 MB it should create 4 output datasets
b) If i receive a file of 9 MB it should create only one output dataset

I was hoping that it could be done through a sort card or if there is an approach that i can take in this case or if someone had faced a similar scenario and handled them.

Where do i start

1. Tried creating an rexx program that can do this, but my knowledge of rexx is zero . tried using ChatGPT but that didn't get me anywhere
2. Browsed all the forums for a similar scenario but couldn't get any that fits this requirement.

Comment: "If I receive a file of 42 MB it should create 4 output datasets" Why?  Shouldn't the result be four 10 MB output files and one 2 MB output file?  You need to determine the size of the input file, read the header record, and split the remaining records into 10MB files.  I'd recommend a single COBOL program, but I don't remember COBOL being able to have an indeterminate number of output files at compile time.

Comment: Is this about splitting a mainframe data set? If so, what are the attributes of the data set?